# Complex message templates in Dark Souls 3

Tags: dark-souls-3

Occasionally I come across messages which seem to follow a template which I don't have available to me (for example, see the below screenshot).

How do you leave messages like this? Can you acquire more complex message templates somehow?

[image: screenshot of message]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While in the message menu, press "Y" (Xbox) or Triangle (PlayStation) to cycle through the different template/gesture combinations.

This includes the "simple" template (one phrase with a blank to fill), and the "complex" template (two phrases with blanks to fill, linked by a conjunctive word/phrase).

Comment: @BrianGordon No problem! It's really easy to miss.